# Find all element of order 5 in $Z^*_{36}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I brute force the solution of order 5 in $Z^*_{36}$ by using the following $a^5 \equiv 1 \mod 36$ and I see that there is no solution for this. However, I don't quite know how to prove this. Can someone help me?

Comment: $a^5\equiv 1$ has _at least_ one solution no matter what you mod by: consider $a\equiv 1$.

Comment: See the duplicates [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730196/number-of-order-5-elements-in-mathbbz-31-mathbbz-times) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976204/how-to-systematically-find-all-the-elements-ℤ-19ℤ∗-with-order-6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\mathbb Z_{36}^*$ has order $12$. Therefore, the order of each of its elements must divide $12$.

Comment: Can you show how you get order 12 in $Z^*_{36}$? Because $(12)^5 \not\equiv 1 \mod 36$

Comment: The order of $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is $\phi(n)$ and $\phi(36)=12$.

Comment: But I want to find element of order 5 in $Z^*_{36}$, but not element of order 12.

Comment: The order of a *group* is the number of elements of that group!

Comment: So does that mean there is 5 element in the order of 5 in $Z^*_{36}$?

Comment: No. It means that there are $\mathbf0$ elements of order $5$.

Comment: Because there is no element in order of 5 is divisible by 12?

Comment: No. Because the order of an element always divides the order of the group. And $5\nmid12$.

Comment: Okay I got it! Thank you!